# Extract math expressions from latex document in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, latex

I'm relatively new to Java and don't really know how to solve this problem. 
I have a Latex document with several math expressions. I need to extract math expressions and assign each formula to the different strings. 
Basicly, I have to take all characters between $...$, $$...$$, (...), etc. and assign each expression to the new String.

Can I solve this problem by assigning whole file to the string and then using regex? Or it is not a good idea, sice Latex files can be huge with a lot of formulae, and I should better read file character by character and find $, (, etc. symbols, and copy characters till the next $, ), etc.

Comment: I guess that question is pretty broad for stackoverflow. There are a number of options. The choice would depend on a number of parameters, including how huge your files are compared to the memory (RAM) available for your Java program.

Comment: Try reading your entire file into a String. If you can do that, you can probably proces it there too. If reading it fails, you obviously cannot.

Comment: Consider using Flex to get rid of anything else, then do your thing with Java.

Comment: @javid Is your file a single line of text? If it is not you can read the file line by line (for example, with java.io.BufferedReader) and match against your regular expression. In that case the memory footprint may be smaller.

Comment: @AndriySimonov thank you for the comment. That is what i'm trying to do right now. This method can work until the expression is in single line. If the formula expressed in two lines, then this is not going to work.

Comment: @javid If an expression takes more than one line you can figure that out with a regular expression as well, then concatenate lines, finally to match again to extract the expression.